# Why does the solution to the wave equation define two directions?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, wave

I've been studying transmission lines recently and I'm struggling to reconcile my intuition with the derivations.  Take the form of the general solution to the wave equation given on this page [antenna theory](http://www.antenna-theory.com/tutorial/txline/transmission2.php) (a great resouce, by the way) and here it is:
[image]

You'll find these formula in many texts and all over the web.  A particularly good derivation is given by the (equally suave) Roger Moore (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayrbIgq_5Ck).

However, when I think of waves travelling down a line, I think of them travelling in a single direction.  I understand that they can be reflected and travel in the opposite direction and so, are free to move in either direction.  In the initial part of the derivation given by Roger, the assumption is made that "the total displacement from equilibrium" is given by

$$f\left ( x - ct \right ) + g\left ( x + ct \right )$$

and the general solution simply falls out of this initial assumption.

But, I'm struggling to see this.  How can the wave be defined to travel in both directions at once?  Or is it that the solution allows for the possibility of one direction or another, in which case V- or V+ is zero.  I can see how the solution might work for waves crossing (superposition), but then aren't they two separate waves??  Confused!

Comment: You say you understand that reflections travel in the opposite directions but then you struggle to see that travel can be in both directions at once? Do you realize that with a continuous forward wave hitting a section where a reflection occurs you get simultaneous forward and reflected waves.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I do understand that, thinking about it.  I visualize the wave folding back on itself with the forward part still in motion and the reflected part now traveling in the opposite direction.

Comment: So Andy, am I correct thinking the solution allows for all combinations: forward, backwards and the overlapping scenario you just mentioned?

Comment: Yes it does and when you get forward and backwards situation overlapping you get a phenomena called standing waves and these can be observed quite often when oceanic waves crash against a sea wall and get reflected back. The water appears to stand still but undulates up and down.

Comment: Yes, I thinking I'm starting to see it better now (as is often the case when I post here!). The solution effectively "draws" the wave shape and that's true even if it bends back on itself.  What's interesting is that the analysis takes the lumped area to a length impossibly smaller than any wavelength, so maybe that intrinsic "folding" must be revealed??